# Couldn't be able to access the Methods and Variables by using Inheritance Concept

Tags: java, testing, automation, jdeveloper

In the class level, I've created methods and declared variables. When I'm calling the methods in the `main` method, it's throwing an error as :

> No enclosing instance of type HirachyInha is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type HirachyInha (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of HirachyInha).

```
package day11;

public class HirachyInha {

    class Parent {
        void display(int a) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }

    class Child1 extends Parent {
        void show(int b) {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }

    class Child2 extends Parent {
        void print(int c) {
            System.out.println(c);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child1 child1 = new Child1();

        child1.display(100);
        child1.show(200);
    }
}
```

Not understanding why am getting an error while calling the methods from `main` method.

Comment: please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/85421) . . . and try to learn about `static`, nested classes and inner classes to solve your problem

Comment: is this really related to JDeveloper, automation and testing? Please check the description of the tags to see if they fit: [tag:jdeveloper] , [tag:automation]  , [tag:testing]

Answer (score 0):

use the keyword static with the inner classes. that should take care of this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are nesting the `Parent`, `Child1`, and `Child2` classes within the `HirachyInha` class. That means they are tied to an instance of the outer class, here `HirachyInha`. But the `main` method is static (i.e., not bound to an instance of the `HirachyInha` class), and you don't create an instance of the `HirachyInha` class, so you cannot access the inner classes. See the [nested / inner classes tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for details.

Usually you use inner classes for classes that are tied closely together, for example, the [`Map.Entry`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) is closely tied to `Map`.

To get your example to work, you can either move the inner classes out of `HirachyInha` (still within the same .java file) or give each class its own .java file. I'd usually go with each class in its own file, unless the inner classes are really a detail of the outer class, like `Map` with `MapItem`. Having one class per file is [Java convention](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-fileorganization.html) and it makes it easy to find a class.

Alternatively, you can declare the inner classes as `static` (e.g., `static class Parent`). That way you don't need an instance of `HirachyInha` to use them. Again, I'd only do this when these classes are really related. In your case it looks like you just put them into `HirachyInha` to have only one class in the file, or for grouping reasons, but not because they are logically related.

If you keep non-static inner classes, you can use them as member variables of the outer class, for example:

```java
Child1 c1;

public HirachyInha() {
    c1 = new Child1();
}

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    HirachyInha hi = new HirachyInha();
    hi.c1.display(100);
}
```

Or, as the compiler error says:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HirachyInha hi = new HirachyInha();
    Child1 c = hi.new Child1();
    c.display(100);
}
```

(Unrelated: there is no error thrown; throwing implies that something can catch the exception. You get a compiler error. Your class file does not even exist, and can certainly not catch anything.)